# PHP database result Array in Javascript Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to get results from the database put them in an array, get them via javascript and check if a value is set.

**CalendarController.php**

```
 public function tasks($id)
{
     $tasks = task::Findtasks()->select('tasks.*', 'tasks_times.*', 'tasks.name as title')
                               ->where('project_id', '=', $id)
                               ->join('tasks_times', 'tasks.id', '=', 'tasks_times.task_id')
                               ->get();

     return view('testcalendar', compact('tasks'));
}
```

as you can see i'm giving tasks to the view..

Now i have this piece of javascript script in a script tag on the "testcalendar" view.

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
        var dataHoje = new Date();
        var completed = <?php echo json_encode($tasks); ?>;
        var tasks = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($tasks); ?>')
        for (var i = 0; i < completed.length; i++) {

        if (completed[i]['completed'] == 1) {
         //event.color = "Groenoe"; 
         element.css('background-color', '#0eb505');
    } else if (event.start < dataHoje && event.end < dataHoje) {
        //event.color = "Rood"; 
        element.css('background-color', '#fc0000');
    } else if (event.start > dataHoje && event.end > dataHoje) {
        //event.color = "Blauw"; 
        element.css('background-color', '#27bec6');
    }       
        }

},
```

so when "completed" = 1 i want the background-color to turn green. (Yes completed is a column in the database)

Thank you

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: @rahman qaiser when "completed" = 1 i want the background-color to turn green. (Yes completed is a column in the database)

Comment: element.css('background-color', 'green');?

Comment: @RahmanQaiser Yes.. That's exactly what i'm using in my code, i can't tell if you are being serious or not..

Comment: can you place your html code too?

Comment: @RahmanQaiser https://pastebin.com/fRkBA6Qc

Comment: still havent figured it out, anyone can help?

Comment: events: [
                        {
                            title: 'All Day Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                            url: 'http://google.com/',
                            color: '#419CE5'
                        } } , if that might help , you can set the event background color that way